# Change postgreSQL database user from windows user in CMD

Tags: postgresql

i recently installed PostgreSQL on windows 7, each time i try to use CMD to execute SQL command, i get this error

`createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "R-61"`

Where R-61 is my windows machine username.

Here is how i use CMD with pgSQL

- first i cd to the pgSQL bin folder `$ cd C:\xampp\pgsql\9.1\bin`
- i try creating a database `$ createdb NEWDATABASE`
- i get a prompt to enter a password. this is where am confuse as i do not know what password.
  I have tried my window user password, password for the `postgres` super user, none seem to work. this is the error message i get 
  `createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "R-61"`

  Anybody know the solution to this?
  am thinking changing the user form R-61 to `postgres` superuser would work but i do not know how to do it.

Your help is greatly needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`createdb` is a command that has to connect to the server just like any other client command (even when run on the server itself), and as such requires a database user to connect with.

If you don't specify a database user with `-U username` option, it takes your OS username, hence the reference to `"R-61"` in the error message. The password that is asked is the password of a non-existing `R-61` database user.

There are also other options such as the host defaulting to `localhost` and the port defaulting to `5432`, see its [manual page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createdb.html) for all of them.

Since you mention that you know the postgres superuser password, the simplest solution would be to use the `postgres` user to initiate the command. It makes sense anyway, because on a fresh install this user would the only one that has the permission to create a database.

Try `createdb -U postgres newdatabase`

It should ask for a password, and that will be the password of the `postgres` database user.

If it doesn't ask for a password, it means that the security policy in `pg_hba.conf` is configured that way. If the password is lost (or no password has ever been set, which is the case for some automated installs, especially on Unix), `pg_hba.conf` has to be changed and the service reloaded to authorize passwordless connections, at least temporarily to set a new password.

Comment: A glance through PG manual should have answered my question.  
Thanks dude for saving my ass

Answer (score 0):

I don't have direct experience with this but I looked into it and I think this is what you're looking for.
I found a similar issue that suggests that PostgresSQL on Windows asks for a password during install.
That password is probably the password for the administrator account for PostgresSQL.
The admin account should work to connect to that database and adjust the permissions for it.

Alternatively, editing the pg_hba.conf file to trust user connections from certain users and locations should let you connect as well.
You will want to correct the permission issue  and revert the edited pg_hba.conf lines.

The discussion I found this on:
[Re: Default password](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/b9e2597c0905061106o1db54c83gae31f44bf0d27902@mail.gmail.com)
Documentation on the pg_hba.conf file:
[19.1. The pg_hba.conf File](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)